# Change android status bar notification every day

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create a constant notification on status bar (like current battery percents - it's always there), but the icon will be changed every day on 00:00.

In addition, I want this notification will alert automatically after rebooting the device and not only after the user opens the application.

I created the notification in MainActivity, but I don't know how to make it alert after rebooting and also I don't know how to change it every day at mid-night.

I tried to create AlarmService and broadcast reciever but it run every 5 seconds and it's far too much so I deleted it.

My current code is:

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
              .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationTitle))
              .setContentText(....)
              .setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap)
              .setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier("icon_status_" + myHelper.getCurrentImageNumber(),"drawable", getPackageName()));  // change the icon at mid-night. 'getCurrentImageNumber' should get me the right icon number

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;


            mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mylHelper.myRequestCode, notification);
```

Right now I see a notification, but the icon doesn't change and it does not alarm after reboot. I saw some answers in stackoverflow but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont give you all the code, you will need to learn by doing.

Here is what you should do:

1 Use a Service to launch your notification and maintain the logic to updating it. If the notification already exists you can update the existing one or programmatically dismiss it and replace with a new one.

2 Register a broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml with multiple intent filters to launch your service.

```
<receiver android:name=".myReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
     </intent-filter>

     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3 Create class which extends the broadcast receiver class and use and launch the above service.

Comment: Do I need to register my service in AndroidManifest.xml too? yesterday this was what caused it to run every 5 seconds

Comment: Yes, you do need to register it here too. You will have a broadcast receiver which launches a service in response to receiving one of the two above intent filters (TIME_TICK, BOOT_COMPLETED). Your broadcast receiver should have the logic to only launch the service if the time is 00:00 or your device has just booted. Post some more code if you like for more suggestions!